# VK получить hash из запроса

Tags: вконтакте

Здравствуйте!
Можно ли из url получить сгенерированный на сервере vk hash? Например, когда я отправляю запрос vk на получение аудио, он генерирует хэш, который я могу увидеть в отладчике браузера. Можно ли получить его программно?

Comment: если `js`, то `location.hash`, собссн .....

Comment: Уточните, о каком хэше идёт речь. Ничего не понятно.